# state controller is reconstructed un-expectedly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states:

```
  .state('a.b', {
    url: "",
    views: {
      "b": {
        template: require('./ab.html'),            
        controller: ABController
    }
  })
  .state('a.b.c', {
    url: "/:someid",
    views: {
      "c": {                                            
        template: require('./abc.html'),            
        controller: ABCController
    }
  })
```

with ab.html:

```
<div ui-view="c"></div>
```

When I navigate from state a.b to state a.b.c, I see the `ABController` being reconstructed while when I navigate from state a.b.c to a.b, ABContoller is not reconstructed.

What I really want to achieve is to not reconstruct ABContoller when navigating from a.b to a.b.c or from a.b.c to a.b. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is that this is indeed possible and it is what happens by default because, as I was expecting it, ui-router does track carefully what states need to be destroyed/created based on the from and to states.

In this case, what triggered the extra construction is the fact that two of my states used the same parameter variable which forced ui-router to consider the common elements of the state path to be different.

Basically, the fix involved removing an unused/buggy "params" attribute from a state definition.